# How to pattern match multiple words and replace it in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, pattern-matching, regexp-replace, search-multiple-words

There is a table with columns word and sentence. I am trying to replace the words in a sentence if the word exits in "words" column.

Tried the below code but it works only for single word. But I need to replace multiple terms if it exits in the word column.

```
Create table temp(id NUMBER,
word VARCHAR2(1000),
Sentence VARCHAR2(2000));

insert into temp(1,'automation testing','automation testing is popular kind of testing');
insert into temp(2,'testing','manual testing');
insert into temp(3,'manual testing','this is an old method of testing');

BEGIN
for t1 in (select id, word from temp)
LOOP
    for t2 in (select rownum from temp where sentence is not null)
    LOOP
        update temp 
        set sentence = REPLACE(sentence, t1.word,t1.id)
        where rownum = rownum;
    END LOOP;
END LOOP;
END;
```

But I need to replace multiple terms if it exits in the word column.

```
Expected outcome:

id word                   sentence
1  automation testing     1 is popular kind of 2
2  testing                3
3  manual testing         this is an old method of 2
```

```
Updated code:

MERGE INTO temp dst
USING (
  WITH ordered_words ( rn, id, word, regex_safe_word ) AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY LENGTH( word ) ASC, word DESC ),
           id,
           word,
           REGEXP_REPLACE( word, '([][)(}{|^$\.*+?])', '\\\1' )
    FROM   temp
  ),
  sentences_with_ids ( rid, sentence, rn ) AS (
    SELECT ROWID,
           sentence,
           ( SELECT COUNT(*) + 1 FROM ordered_words )
    FROM   temp
  UNION ALL
    SELECT s.rid,
           REGEXP_REPLACE(
             REGEXP_REPLACE(
               s.sentence,
               '(^|\W)' || w.regex_safe_word || '($|\W)',
               '\1${'|| w.id ||'}\2'
              ),
             '(^|\W)' || w.regex_safe_word || '($|\W)',
             '\1${' || w.id || '}\2'
           ),
           s.rn - 1
    FROM   sentences_with_ids s
           INNER JOIN ordered_words w
           ON ( s.rn - 1 = w.rn ) 
  ),
  sentences_with_words ( rid, sentence, rn ) AS (
    SELECT rid,
           sentence,
           ( SELECT COUNT(*) + 1 FROM ordered_words )
    FROM   sentences_with_ids
    WHERE  rn = 1
  UNION ALL
    SELECT s.rid,
           REPLACE(
             s.sentence,
             '${' || w.id || '}',
             'http://localhost/' || w.id || '/<u>' || w.word || '</u>'
           ),
           s.rn - 1
    FROM   sentences_with_words s
           INNER JOIN ordered_words w
           ON ( s.rn - 1 = w.rn ) 
  )
  SELECT rid, sentence
  FROM   sentences_with_words
  WHERE  rn = 1
) src
ON ( dst.ROWID = src.RID )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET    sentence = src.sentence;
```

Can we improve the performance of the above updated query?

Comment: In sentence 2, how can you tell that the result should be "3" instead of "manual 2"?

Comment: Good point @kfinity. If we have the exact word in the word column, we have to replace it. Say, if we din't have manual testing(id =3), we just had to do replace testing. That would be manual testing as you mentioned.

Comment: The words could be `1 = automation 2`, `2 = testing` and `3 = manual 2` then you can replace `testing` with `2` and then `automation 2` with `1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2019-09-13 13:51 UTC - I see what you are getting at now. You want to replace not strings but words, and the new string will **include** the word(s). So you are doing a first series of replacements, then a second series.

To make this go faster, I would still do a JOIN of the words to the sentences in which they are found. Here is the SELECT part of the solution (the bit that goes into the USING clause) so you can check what goes on and see some results quicker. Some words of explanation after the code.

```
with words(id, word, word_length, search1, replace1, search2, replace2) as (
  select id, word, length(word),
  '(^|\W)' || REGEXP_REPLACE(word, '([][)(}{|^$\.*+?])', '\\\1') || '($|\W)',
  '\1{'|| id ||'}\2',
  '{'|| id ||'}',
  'http://localhost/' || id || '/<u>' || word || '</u>'
  FROM temp
)
, joined_data as (
  select w.search1, w.replace1, w.search2, w.replace2,
    s.rowid s_rid, s.sentence,
    row_number() over(partition by s.rowid order by word_length desc) rn
  from words w
  join temp s
  on instr(s.sentence, w.word) > 0
  and regexp_like(s.sentence, w.search1)
)
, unpivoted_data as (
  select S_RID, SENTENCE, PHASE, SEARCH_STRING, REPLACE_STRING,
    row_number() over(partition by s_rid order by phase, rn) rn,
    case when row_number() over(partition by s_rid order by phase, rn)
      = count(*) over(partition by s_rid)
      then 1
      else 0
    end is_last
  from joined_data
  unpivot(
    (search_string, replace_string) 
    for phase in ( (search1, replace1) as 1, (search2, replace2) as 2 ))
)
, replaced_data(S_RID, RN, is_last, SENTENCE) as (
  select S_RID, RN, is_last,
    regexp_replace(SENTENCE, search_string, replace_string)
  from unpivoted_data
  where rn = 1
  union all
  select n.S_RID, n.RN, n.is_last,
    case when n.phase = 1
      then regexp_replace(o.SENTENCE, n.search_string, n.replace_string)
      else replace(o.SENTENCE, n.search_string, n.replace_string)
    end
  from unpivoted_data n
  join replaced_data o
    on o.s_rid = n.s_rid and n.rn = o.rn + 1  
)
select s_rid, sentence from replaced_data
where is_last = 1
order by s_rid;
```

The WORDS subquery gets the word length and the "search" and "replace" strings for both series of replacements.

JOINED_DATA joins the words to the sentences. I do INSTR first and do REGEXP only when needed because it costs more CPU.

UNPIVOTED_DATA splits the rows into two phases: the first replaces "automation testing" by "{1}" and the second replaces "{1}" by "http://localhost/1/automation testing". The rows are assigned the right sequence, and the "last" row for each sentence is identified.

REPLACED_DATA does either REGEXP_REPLACE or REPLACE depending on the phase. In the second phase, REPLACE is enough.

Regards,
Stew

Comment: This works, Stew. Thank you. But it's case sensitive as we are using INSTR. Can we use REGEXP_INSTR? Does that affect the performance?

Comment: If you want case insensitive, remove the INSTR completely and just use REGEXP_LIKE: "on regexp_like(s.sentence, w.search1, 'i')". I don't know how much difference that will make to performance, but fast enough is fast enough. Why not just try it?

Comment: I tried it, Stew. Th performance is really low. Can't we use REGEXP_INSTR and REGEXP_LIKE both?

Comment: First, you would never need to do both, just one or the other. Second, I don't see why either one would be faster than the other. So, why not "on instr( upper(s.sentence), upper(w.word) ) > 0  and regexp_like(s.sentence, w.search1, 'i')". The INSTR part makes sure the "word" is in the text, the REGEXP_LIKE confirms that it is a word and not just part of a word.

Comment: I got it, Stew. While replacing in replaced_data, it was case sensitive. I changed regexp_replace to include 'i' now. It replaces fine. But in words, we are selecting the word from the temp table to create replace1 values ('http://localhost/' || id || '/<u>' || word || '</u>'), it picks up the same case (lower/upper from the table). In the final replace, it replaces we the same case. I want the case to be the same as in the sentence column. For e.g. If the word is Testing and the sentence is automation testing, I am expecting the final replace to be automation http://localhost/2/<u>testing<u>.

Comment: Is there a way to check the case in the sentence and retain the same case while replacing?

Comment: There is a way to retain the same case: have "Testing" as a word and "testing" as a word, then do case sensitive checking and replacing.

Comment: Yes, that's a good point. But I have a table of about 50k words and sentences. This option would not be feasible right?

Comment: Also Stew, I have posted another question 58023599. It would be really helpful if you can answer that. It just a little enhancement for the code above. Thank you.

Comment: "I have a table of about 50k words and sentences." I just don't get that. You should have a table of the from/to words you want and a table of the sentences you want to change. It makes no sense to put them together.

Comment: " I have posted another question 58023599. It would be really helpful if you can answer that." One thing at a time. First, has *this* question been answered? If so, mark your preferred answer as correct.

Comment: Thanks, Stew. You have been really helpful. This worked!

Answer (score 1):

Use `REGEXP_REPLACE` to do the replacements.  Do them in descending order of word length, so you replace "automation testing" occurrences before "testing" occurrences.

Sample code:

```
with function word_replace ( p_sentence VARCHAR2 ) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
  l_working VARCHAR2(800) := p_sentence;
BEGIN
  FOR r IN ( SELECT word, id FROM temp ORDER BY length(word) desc, id ) LOOP
    l_working := regexp_replace(l_working, r.word, r.id);
  END LOOP;
  return l_working;
END;
SELECT sentence, word_replace(sentence) 
FROM   temp;
```

> ```
> +-----------------------------------------------+----------------------------+
> |                   SENTENCE                    |   WORD_REPLACE(SENTENCE)   |
> +-----------------------------------------------+----------------------------+
> | automation testing is popular kind of testing | 1 is popular kind of 2     |
> | manual testing                                | 3                          |
> | this is an old method of testing              | this is an old method of 2 |
> +-----------------------------------------------+----------------------------+
> ```

Comment: This is what I am expecting. Thank you. But how do we update it the replaced sentence temp.sentence?

Comment: Probably the easiest way is to put `word_replace` function into a package.  Then `UPDATE temp SET sentence = my_pkg.word_replace(sentence)`.

Answer (score 0):

I expect this is too complicated for you, but it turns out everything can be done in one SQL statement.

```
merge into temp o
using (
  select s_rid, sentence, is_last from (
    select s.rowid s_rid, w.id word_id, w.word,
      cast(replace(s.sentence, w.word, w.id) as varchar2(4000)) sentence,
      length(w.word) word_length
    from temp w join temp s
    on instr(s.sentence, w.word) > 0
  )
  model
    partition by (s_rid)
    dimension by (
      row_number() over(partition by s_rid order by word_length desc, word) rn
    )
    measures(word_id, word, sentence, 0 is_last)
  rules (
    sentence[rn > 1] = replace(sentence[cv()-1], word[cv()], word_id[cv()]),
    is_last[any] = presentv(is_last[cv()+1], 0, 1)
  )
) n
on (o.rowid = n.s_rid and n.is_last = 1)
when matched then update set o.sentence = n.sentence;
```

Note that if you run the MERGE twice, the second time it will not make any changes. This shows that no unnecessary updates are made. The logic:

1. First I join the words to the sentences where the word is found in the sentence. This eliminates any sentences where no replacement needs to be done. I keep the ROWID of the sentence for later use.
2. The MODEL clause will partition by sentence and order by descending word length.
3. The "rule" in the MODEL clause will do each replacement in turn, and it will identify the last row for each original sentence.
4. Using MERGE, I can join the result to the table using the ROWID and then update the SENTENCE column.

Best regards,
Stew Ashton

Comment: Thank you Stew for the detailed explanation. Which of these methods would you think would be efficient for the table of about 60k records? Basically, each of the 60k words will be checked against each sentence (60k).

Comment: It mostly depends on how many rows come out of the join. If none of the words are found in any of the sentences, all three of my solutions will be equally efficient. If every word is found in every sentence, the join will result in 60K*60K rows and there will be lots of extra work. In the past, for similar problems I have found MODEL to be somewhat more efficient because it can use PARTITION BY to break the problem down into smaller pieces.

Comment: How about doing a SELECT /*+ NO_MERGE */ COUNT(*) FROM(...) where '...' is the join query? Then let us know how many rows come back.

Comment: Looks like MODEL is efficient. But it's replacing all the occurrences even if the word is in between another word. I am actually not replacing with its ids. I am replacing like http://localhost/id/word. For example mobile. If mobile and mob exist in a sentence, it replaces mobile and then mob as well. So, it will be http://localhost/123/http://localhost/456/mob/ile

Comment: So what do you want to happen? Are you saying you want to replace words and not strings? If you replace 'gang' with 'mob', what about 'gangs'? Please provide new test data that shows what you really want, with expected results.

Comment: Can you please look in to the db_fiddle?With the help of your code we could get to this. 
```
https://dbfiddle.uk/rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=bbcaada7f66885bb8f9a80e223ebe2c7
```
There is a situation here. The value to be replaced is localhost/"id"/<u>"word"<u> If you see the value for id = 5 (B-number analysis) the sentence is localhost/6/<u>http://localhost/5/<u>B-number analysis<u> table<u> But the actual value is supposed to be localhost/6/<u>B-number analysis table<u>

Comment: Not Found
The requested URL /rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=bbcaada7f66885bb8f9a80e223ebe2c7 was not found on this server.

Comment: Hi Stew, I have modified the post to include the Updated code. Can we improve the performance of the code? It replaces the perfectly but runs more than 15 hours and still running for 45k records.

Comment: I don't understand why your query does what it does. The chances of getting the right answer quicker are much better if we understand the logic behind the query. I would work better with decent test data (including edge cases), a detailed non-SQL explanation of what you want as a result, and expected outcome. You did provide test data (but not enough apparently) and expected outcome, but it appears you need to explain a lot more.

Comment: Hi Stew, I have posted 58020331, related to the same question. Would it be possible to take a look? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the same logic as the MERGE with MODEL clause, but using PL/SQL.

```
declare
  cursor cur_temp is
    select s.rowid s_rid, w.id word_id, w.word, s.sentence,
      length(w.word) word_length
    from temp w join temp s
    on instr(s.sentence, w.word) > 0
    order by s_rid, word_length desc;
  l_rid rowid;
  l_sentence varchar2(4000);
  procedure upd is
  begin
    update temp set sentence = l_sentence where rowid = l_rid;
  end upd;
begin
  for rec in cur_temp loop
    if rec.s_rid > l_rid then
      upd;
      l_sentence := null;
    end if;
    l_rid := rec.s_rid;
    l_sentence := replace(nvl(l_sentence, rec.sentence), rec.word, rec.word_id);
  end loop;
  upd;
end;
/
```

Regards,
Stew

Answer (score 0):

Since everyone is probably allergic to the MODEL clause, here is an alternative that uses recursive subqueries, which are a SQL standard. This is just the SELECT part, which could be put into the USING clause of a MERGE statement.

```
with joined_data as (
  select s.rowid s_rid, w.id word_id, w.word, s.sentence,
  row_number() over(partition by s.rowid order by length(w.word) desc) rn
  from temp w join temp s
  on instr(s.sentence, w.word) > 0
)
, recursed_data(s_rid, sentence, rn) as (
  select s_rid, replace(sentence, word, word_id), rn
  from joined_data
  where rn = 1
  union all
  select n.s_rid, replace(o.sentence, n.word, n.word_id), n.rn
  from recursed_data o 
  join joined_data n on o.s_rid = n.s_rid and n.rn = o.rn + 1
)
select s_rid,
max(sentence) keep (dense_rank last order by rn) sentence
from recursed_data
group by s_rid;
```

Regards,
Stew

Comment: Hi Stew, I was asking your help with the new question - 58020331 I posted. MT0 has replied. Could you please check if there is a way to tune the query? It consumes all the temp space because of the cross join. Thanks in advance.